# Commands not working in LWUIT

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I extended the Form class in lwuit and created a form class which has two commands, Next and Exit. Then I created a midlet to run that displays the form. The commands are being showed however nothing happens when they are clicked. Here is the code I wrote:

> MainForm.java

```
import com.sun.lwuit.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.GridLayout;

public class MainForm extends Form implements ActionListener{
private Label label;
private RadioButton epl, laliga, seria, uefa, bundesliga;
private Command exit, next;
private String leagueName;
private ButtonGroup bg;
private TestMIDlet midlet;

public MainForm(TestMIDlet midlet){
    this.midlet = midlet;
    setTitle("Main Page");
    GridLayout gl = new GridLayout(6,1);
    setLayout(gl);
    label = new Label("Choose a league to proceed");
    epl = new RadioButton("EPL");
    laliga = new RadioButton("La liga");
    seria = new RadioButton("Seria A");
    bundesliga = new RadioButton("Bundesliga");
    uefa = new RadioButton("UEFA Champions League");
    uefa.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            leagueName = "International Clubs";
        }
    });
    bundesliga.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            leagueName = "Germany";
        }
    });
    seria.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            leagueName = "Italy";
        }
    });
    laliga.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            leagueName = "Spain";
        }
    });
    epl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            leagueName = "England";
        }
    });
    bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(epl);
    bg.add(laliga);
    bg.add(seria);
    bg.add(bundesliga);
    bg.add(uefa);
    next = new Command("Next",2);
    exit = new Command("Exit", 2);
    addComponent(label);
    addComponent(epl);
    addComponent(laliga);
    addComponent(seria);
    addComponent(bundesliga);
    addComponent(uefa);
    addCommand(exit);
    addCommand(next);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Command c = evt.getCommand();
    if (c == exit){
        midlet.destroyApp(false);
        midlet.notifyDestroyed();
    }
    else if (c == next){
            System.out.println(leagueName);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reveiwed your total program and i found the solution for you. See here you implemented the `ActionListener` but you havent added the `CommandListener` to your `Form`. This is the cause that the commands havent been called when you clicked them . Follow the below Code and use it there.

```
this.addCommandListener(this);
```

Now everything works perfect in your code. Let me know if you face any other issue.

Comment: Here i am saying add CommandListner to the Form . Then only it works . First let test this code. It works fine if we add the above code i suggested.

Comment: `CommandListener` is used when you do LCDUI coding. `ActionListener` is used when you do LWUIT coding. The `ActionEvent` object you get with an `ActionListener` contains a `Command` object. There is nothing wrong with using `ActionListener`. I'd rather think it would be considered messy to use `CommandListener` in LWUIT coding.

Comment: here you can do like this ,   this.addCommandListener(new ActionListener() {
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    }
  }); Here you can handle the Action Events. Where in the above, He implemented the ActionListener to his form . So i suggested him like that . Thanks .

Comment: I took a closer look at LWUIT, and found that you're partly right. In order to `Command`s to be caught, you need to `setCommandListener(this);` so I have edited my answer. There is no `addCommandListener()` method though, as you are referring to.

Comment: Look more closer into the LWUIT you will find the addCommandListener to the FORM . Just extend com.sun.lwuit.Form . I am working in LWUIT and i will use the same approach . Thanks

Comment: You're right. There is indeed an `addCommandListener` for the `Form` object. Earlier I looked at this LWUIT example I found: https://lwuit.java.net/tutorial/events.html It demonstrates using `setCommandListener`. I suppose both methods will work then.

Comment: @mr_lou the setCommandListener method was what was confusing me too.In the tutorials and books I read about lwuit, they all use the setCommandListener instead of addCommandListener.However,in the latest version of lwuit(v1.5) the method is replaced with addCommandListener.Anyways, thank you guys for your answer

Comment: Ah well, that explains it then. But you should still use `c.equals(exit)` instead of `c==exit` though. That part is equally important. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare to objects using the equal sign. You have to use the `Object.equals(anotherObject)` method.

Replace your `actionPerformed` method with this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
 Command c = evt.getCommand();
 if (c.equals(exit)){
  midlet.destroyApp(false);
  midlet.notifyDestroyed();
 }
 else if (c.equals(next)) {
  System.out.println(leagueName);
 }
}
```

EDIT:
Also, in order for your `Command`s to be caught, you need to call `setCommandListener(this);`
Or `addCommandListener(this);`